# VBA: Excel stops working after extracting data from other workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to extract data from other 4 workbooks (some of them may have **thousands of rows**)

The Excel stops working, and restarts, after the extraction is completed. 
I have the data extracted in the sheets so I assume that the excel is chrashing after the last workbook data is extracted.

I also tested with only one workbook and it crashes after closing.

I have read that we could use "DoEvents" and "Application.Wait" after copy/paste or close workbook, to let Excel finish some background work. I've tried that but with no success.

Any ideas why the Excel stops running / restarts?

Here is my code:

```
Public sysExtractParamsDictionary As Scripting.dictionary

'Sub rotine triggered when pressing button
Sub Extract()

    Set sysExtractParamsDictionary = mUtils.FillDictionary("sysParams", "tExtractParams")   'Sub rotine belonging to mUtils module to fill dictionary with values from my sysParams sheet. Contains the sheets name.
    mClean.Clean       'Sub rotine belonging to mClean module to clear sheets
    ExtractData [sysInputDirectory], "Input Sheet"  'Cell Name sysInputDirectory
    ExtractData [sysR2Directory], "R1 Sheet"
    ExtractData [sysR2Directory], "R2 Sheet"
    ExtractData [sysR3Directory], "R3 Sheet"

End Sub

Sub ExtractData(sFilePath As String, sDictionaryKey As String)

    Dim oWorkbook As cWorkBook 'Class Module

    Set oWorkbook = New cWorkBook

    mUtils.SetStatusBarMessage True, "Extracting " & sDictionaryKey & " ..."   'Sub rotine belonging to my mUtils module to set on or off status bar message

    oWorkbook.WorkBookDirectory = sFilePath
    oWorkbook.OpenWorkBook oWorkbook.WorkBookDirectory
    oWorkbook.CopiesSourceSheetValuesToDestinationSheet sysExtractParamsDictionary(sDictionaryKey)
    oWorkbook.CloseWorkBook (False)

    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
    DoEvents

    Set oWorkbook = Nothing

End Sub

'#### Class Module

Private wbWorkBook As Workbook
Private sWorkBookDirectory As String
Private sWorkBookName As String
Private wsWorksheet As Worksheet

Public Property Set Workbook(wbNew As Workbook)
    Set wbWorkBook = wbNew
End Property

Public Property Get Workbook() As Workbook
    Set Workbook = wbWorkBook
End Property

Public Property Let WorkBookDirectory(sFilePath As String)
    sWorkBookDirectory = sFilePath
End Property

Public Property Get WorkBookDirectory() As String
    WorkBookDirectory = sWorkBookDirectory
End Property

Public Property Let WorkBookName(sFileName As String)
    sWorkBookName = sFileName
End Property

Public Property Get WorkBookName() As String
    WorkBookName = sWorkBookName
End Property

Public Property Set Worksheet(wsNew As Worksheet)
    Set wsWorksheet = wsNew
End Property

Public Property Get Worksheet() As Worksheet
    Worksheet = wsWorksheet
End Property

Public Property Let WorkBookDirectory(sFilePath As String)
    sWorkBookDirectory = sFilePath
End Property

Public Property Get WorkBookDirectory() As String
    WorkBookDirectory = sWorkBookDirectory
End Property

'Class Module Function to Open WorkBook
Public Sub OpenWorkBook(sFilePath As String)

    Dim oFSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim sLog As String

    sFileName = oFSO.GetFileName(sFilePath) 'Get the File Name from Path

    If sFileName = "" Then
        sLog = "Error. Not possible to retrieve File Name from Directory."
    Else
        Me.WorkBookName = sFileName
        Set Me.Workbook = Workbooks.Open(sFilePath)
        If wbWorkBook Is Nothing Then
            sLog = "Error opening file: " & Me.WorkBookName
        Else
            sLog = "File successfully openned!"
        End If
    End If

    Set oFSO = Nothing

End Sub

'Class Module Function to Copy Values from source to destination
Public Sub CopiesSourceSheetValuesToDestinationSheet(wsDestinationName As Variant)

    Dim wsDestination As Worksheet
    Dim rStartRange As range
    Dim rFullRangeToPaste As range

    Set wsDestination = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(CStr(wsDestinationName)) ' Destination Sheet
    Set Me.Worksheet = Me.Workbook.Sheets(1) 'Source Sheet

    Set rStartRange = wsWorksheet.range("A1")
    Set rFullRangeToPaste = wsWorksheet.range(rStartRange, mUtils.FindLast(3)) 'FindLast is a function belonging to mUtils module to find the last cell in worksheet
    rFullRangeToPaste.Copy wsDestination.Cells(wsDestination.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)

End Sub

'Class Module Function to Close Workbook
Public Sub CloseWorkBook(bSaveChanges As Boolean)
    wbWorkBook.Saved = True
    wbWorkBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub

 '#### End Class Module
```

I've also tried to do it without Class Module (just in case something was wrong with objects), but i still have the same issue.

```
Sub Extract()
 ExtractCopyClose "C:\MyFiles\InputData.csv", "Input"
End Sub

Sub ExtractCopyClose(sFilePath As String, wsDestinationName As String)

    Dim wb As New Workbook
    Dim wsDestination As Worksheet
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim oFSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim sLog As String
    Dim rStartRange As range
    Dim rFullRangeToPaste As range

    sFileName = oFSO.GetFileName(sFilePath) 'Get the File Name from Path

    If sFileName = "" Then
        sLog = "Error. Not possible to retrieve File Name from Directory."
    Else
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sFilePath)
        If wb Is Nothing Then
            sLog = "Error opening file: " & sWorkBookName
        Else
            sLog = "File successfully openned!"
        End If
    End If

    Set oFSO = Nothing

    Set wsDestination = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsDestinationName) ' Destination Sheet
    Set wsSource = wb.Sheets(1) 'Source Sheet

    Set rStartRange = wsSource.range("A1")
    Set rFullRangeToPaste = wsSource.range(rStartRange, mUtils.FindLast(3))
    rFullRangeToPaste.Copy wsDestination.Cells(wsDestination.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)

    wb.Saved = True
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Question edited to simple version of code (without Class Module). The issue remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the sheet I was importing from the other workbook had external connections and was creating Connections and new References in my Workbook. Don't know why, but somehow this was affecting my Excel and causing it to restart since I was copying all the sheet content.

Instead of copying the full source sheet to my workbook...

```
 rFullRangeToPaste.Copy wsDestination.Cells(wsDestination.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
```

I copied only the values and formats of the source sheet...

```
Dim rDestinationRange As Range

'the rest of the code in question
```

<s>`rFullRangeToPaste.Copy wsDestination.Cells(wsDestination.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)`</s>

```
   Set rDestinationRange = wsDestination.Cells(wsDestination.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
    rFullRangeToPaste.Copy    
    wsDestination.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

Note: This worked after my workbook recovered from the previous extraction (without broken external connections and null references). Then I made the changes in the code and save it.